# Assign the result of combined observables before they are defined

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a component that prints the value of an observable via the async pipe.

When the component is initialised, a method in the service is called that asynchronously assign a value to a series of observables. 
I need the service to emit the result of the combination of those observables for the component to print.

The component is not being notified. I think the problem is that when the template is subscribed, the observables that I am combining are not yet defined. Is there any way of making this work?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e5swo)

Comment: Your stackblitz link is not working.

Comment: sorry, it should be fixed now.

Comment: First thing first, It's failing on `pipe` because the `transformedValue$` is not yet defined. I'll have a look more. Just posting my initial thought

Comment: Have you heard of Subjects? Subjects would help you here.

Comment: @pixelbits why would subjects be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all, to simulate HTTP calls you need to use `of()` + `delay()`.
- Also your component is root component, so you will never get value into `@Input` field.
- The main issue, is that you need to combine `init()` and `initTransformedValue()` methods, because if you call `init()` it performs combine latest on observables (or undefined), that you will reassign later in `initTransformedValue()`, so the correct order is **1. call initTransformedValue(), 2. call init(), 3. use result$.** To avoid complexity, it's just better to combine all that stuff into 1 method **getTransformedValue()**, that returns required observable.

[Stackblitz demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1cqkzw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
Hope that helps.

Comment: - Why? if I just want to mock that the assignment will not be syncronous setTimeOut works as well.
- True, I got lost in the Stackblitz and forgot about it
- That makes sense